# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am trying to add SSR in my existing site.
My Angular version is :v8
I followed this link: https://angular.io/guide/universal

```
  [error] TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#<Object>'
    at TapSubscriber._tapNext (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\visitor.js:56:210)
    at TapSubscriber._next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:59:27)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
    at Object.subscribeToResult (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at Observable._subscribe (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\observable\scalar.js:6:20)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (E:\pro\Git\pro\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:39:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following steps to solve error.

1. Install this node package of version

> `install npm package @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.5`

2. then try to build

> `npm build:ssr`